# jQuery callback not firing after rails ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

**Controller**

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.js { render partial: 'post', layout: false, locals: {post: @post}}      
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<div id='posts_container'>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= render partial: 'post', locals: {post: post} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**CoffeeScript**

```
$ ->
  $('#new_post_submit').click ->
    $.post 'posts',
      data: $('#new_post_form').serialize()
      (data) -> $('#posts_container').prepend(data)
    return false
```

I want to return the contents of a partial to my view and dynamically insert it using CoffeeScript. The post request works, the record is created, and chrome shows that rails returned the correct partial in the response.  Any idea why the callback isn't firing to insert it? I suspect it has to do with rails taking over the request so the callback never fires. If so, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: I suspect something trivial, like the callback is being called but `$('#posts_container')` is not finding anything because the ID is misspelled.

Comment: Please show the `post` partial